# Как наследовать геттеры и сеттеры созданные lombock?

Tags: java, lombok

Есть 2 класса:

```
@Data
public class Task {
    String description;
}

@Data
public class CustomTask extends Task {
    String custom;
}
```

Но при попытке использовать `new CustomClass().setDescription(...)` выясняется что у данного экземпляра нет этого сеттера. Возможно ли силами `lombok` это сделать, и если да то как?

Comment: Похоже IDE шалит. Только что проверил - у меня все работает (IDEA и Lombok плагин)...

Comment: Тоже не наблюдаю никаких проблем, при компиляции и запуске в консоли.

Comment: @Cepr0 да это IDEA глючила